# c# Thread syncronization problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

So I'm seeing ***fun*** stuff playing with threads.

I have a method that starts 2 threads and goes on with its life and I tried doing the following to keep things safe.

```
    bool CopyOk1 = false;
    bool CopyOk2 = false;
    new Thread(() => FirstMethod(tempList1, ref CopyOk1)).Start();
    new Thread(() => SecondMethod(tempList2, ref CopyOk2)).Start();
    var spinner = new SpinWait();
    while (!CopyOk1 || !CopyOk2)
        spinner.SpinOnce();
```

then in both methods I start with the following

```
    private static void FirstMethod(List<T> templist, ref bool CopyOk)
    {
        var temp = new T[templist.Count];
        templist.CopyTo(temp);
        CopyOk = true;
        //moves on
    }
```

My intention here is to copy the passed list so I can change and use it safely inside the threads ASAP to unblock the caller thread.

My problem is that on the second method unpredictably, between the array initialization and the list CopyTo the base list changes, somehow, by something.

These lists are created inside the caller thread and are not actually used after the threads are started so I have absolutely ***NO*** idea how/why this is happening.

No doubt I'm doing something wrong here, but my noobish skills won't let me see, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you add the code above that defines and assigns tempList1 & 2?

Comment: I believe @bryanmac totally nailed it. The source of templist could be modified after templist was defined.

Comment: It seems highly likely that you're sharing some values (references) between the two tempLists. Show us the code that populates them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the code that you posted suggests that you are doing anything wrong.  The problem has to lie elsewhere- most likely, as commenters have suggested, in the code that populates List1/List2.  If you are threading that as well, perhaps you are not waiting for that thread to finish populating the lists before proceeding?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of locking 'templist', use a global lock. Then protect **all** code that modifies the source list with that same lock.

Also, perhaps an aside, but waiting for a thread to partially complete can be done more elegantly, i.e not involving a loop. Using a ManualResetEvent will allow your original thread to wait for 'something' to occur in other threads. Using WaitOne will block the thread until a Set() is called in the other thread.

```
private object m_Lock = new object();
private ManualResetEvent m_ResetOne = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private ManualResetEvent m_ResetTwo = new ManualResetEvent(false);

(...)

new Thread(() => FirstMethod(tempList1)).Start();
new Thread(() => SecondMethod(tempList2)).Start();
m_ResetOne.WaitOne();
m_ResetTwo.WaitOne();

(...)

private void FirstMethod(List<T> templist)
{
    lock (m_Lock)
    {
        var temp = new T[templist.Count];
        templist.CopyTo(temp);
    }
    m_ResetOne .Set();
    //moves on
}
```

Comment: The manual reset looks good, will try it somewhere, but in this particular problem unfortunately won't help as i really really really over-simplified things in the example. But I learned something new with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check the behavior

```
private static void FirstMethod(List<T> templist, ref bool CopyOk)
{
    T[] temp;

    lock (templist)
    {
        temp = new T[templist.Count];
        templist.CopyTo(temp);
    }
    CopyOk = true;
    //moves on
}
```

Comment: This would only fix if templist were being modified after the threads were started.

Comment: @Thiago: which you claim it isn't, and yet you claim it is. If you have a problem you don't understand, don't disregard any suggestions.

Comment: This would solve the problem if you were locking on the lists everywhere, but would by itself do nothing functionally significant.

Comment: The list is reference, so it does not matter. Another problem is that the list may not be syched on caller side.

Comment: @Charles: You right. my comment above is just about the same thing :)

Comment: Kef and @Charles sorry if I sounded rude, didn't mean to. Sometimes I forget about the whole reference world, I'm actually a DBA delving into programming. The problem here was truly where the tempLists were coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You need some type of synchronization mechanism to prevent `List<T>` from being changed.  We can't see enough code in the current sample to warrant that it is not being altered.